# csrf_token not created on pages loaded via post

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-csrf, csrf-protection

I have an issue with the `{% csrf_token %}` template tag in Django. On pages loaded via get it is fine but if I use post to load a page the tag is not loaded to forms on the page requested with post.

I am using `render_to_response` to render the pages

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you updating your context with the csrf token when calling `render_to_response` from a POST request? Like so:

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        c = {}
        c.update(csrf(request))
        return render_to_response("a_template.html", c)
    else:
        # GET code...
```